# Where is the list of groovy variants that I can select?

Tags: ros, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to build groovy on ubuntu 12.4, following [www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source) .

The following works fine
roslocate info ackermann_msgs

but if I try to get info for desktop or desktop-full variants, as described at ros.org/reps/rep-0131.html#variants , I get

```
~/ros$ roslocate info desktop
cannot locate information about desktop
```

Where is the list of variants that I can select?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49373/where-is-the-list-of-groovy-variants-that-i-can-select?/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on 2012-11-29**:
thanks! (I have not enough karma to post a comment on the answer)
When I run apt-cache search ros-groovy I get many groovy packages, but not the variant one. Maybe because I'm in 32bits and beta is only available for 64?

**Comment by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on 2012-11-29**:
thanks!
When I run apt-cache search ros-groovy I get many groovy packages, but not the variant one. Maybe because I'm in 32bits and beta is only available for 64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslocate indicates the source or (meta-)packages.

Variants listed in rep-131 will show up as
ros-groovy-desktop

when you run

```
 apt-cache search ros-groovy | grep variant
```

For a list of packages, there will be a website here where you can use the name of the variant, e.g.:
http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/groovy/desktop
but this is currently work-in-progress, so expect things to break before groovy release.

Once this is stable, instructions to install from source will be at
http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2